# Android TableLayout Add new Row with data from EditText by clicking a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, tablelayout

I have an empty `tablelayout` setup on the `MainActivity` and I have another activity called `Add_Item` where I have a few `EditText`'s where the user can submit information to add to the `tablelayout`. The part im stuck on is how to actually save the data inserted into the `EditText`into a new row each time the user presses the save button. Is there a tutorial some where on how to do this with example code? I am only finding ones with sql which I do not need. Below is the code I have so far of the XML and `Add_Item` activity

//Add_Item Activity

```
package com.example.moduleonesimpleapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Add_Item extends ActionBarActivity {
    //variables
    EditText TaskNameET;
    Spinner SpinType;
    Button SaveTodo;
    String SpinnerOptions[] = {"OptionOne", "OptionTwo", "OptionThree"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__item);

        //define vars
        TaskNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TaskNameET);
        SpinType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        SaveTodo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> ard=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SpinnerOptions);
        SpinType.setAdapter(ard);

        //onclick todobutton
        SaveTodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //here is the save button, I would like to save the information inputted from the TaskNameET EditText Into the TableLayout
                // I have the tablelayout defined as TableRow
                //MainActivity.this.TableRow.setTextAlignment();
                Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add__item, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//XML for tablelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.moduleonesimpleapplication.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/AddItemButton" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

       <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got's your gut feelings telling? It should be telling you by now, that this approach you have followed is a dead end, a roadblock. Well, technically you hack your way through and dynamically add rows to the `TableLayout` but that's all is going to be...a hack. Why? Because, there are far better options and features that ship with the Android SDK.

Either way, you will need to persist the data users enter in some way. While sqlite is not the only option, IMO, it is the most scalable solution. Here are some ideas...

- Forget about the `TableLayout` use a `ListView` instead
- Store the data use enters in memory if there's no need to persist it across different application sessions and if the data is not huge
- Store the data in a file or preferences if it needs to be persisted and it's not huge
- Store the in a SQLite database...HIGHLY recommended

Now, go ahead and google some tutorials using the terms I pointed above, but don't ask for a tutorial here since it goes against the Terms of use of this site. Good luck

Comment: darn! I was using ListView before but I was trying to add columns to it so someone suggested that I use TableLayout since that automaticly has columns.. this is a little frustrating but thank you, I will do more research.

Comment: Is a ListView with three columns similar to how the TableLayout possible?

Comment: @ssj3goku878 you can customise the `ListView` to look however you want if define a custom layout for its items